# Just how regular are the sample paths of 1D white noise smoothed with a Gaussian kernel?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, gaussian, analytic-functions, convolution

Adapted from [math stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4694934/just-how-regular-are-the-sample-paths-of-1d-white-noise-smoothed-with-a-gaussian).

**Background**: the prototypical example of---and way to generate---smooth noise is by convolving a one-dimensional white noise process with a Gaussian kernel.

**My question**: beyond smoothness, does one-dimensional white noise convolved with a Gaussian kernel have sample paths that are analytic functions with probability 1? Since there is a lot of existing literature on the sample path regularity of Gaussian processes I am hopeful that this already has been investigated somewhere, however, I haven't found an answer so far. Any help, pointers, or references are appreciated!

**Definitions:**

- White noise: White noise $\omega_t$ is a mean-zero stationary Gaussian process on $t\in \mathbb R$ with autocovariance function given by: $\mathbb E[\omega_t \omega_s]= \delta(t-s)$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta.
- Gaussian kernel: is the function $\Phi_t = e^{-\beta  t^2}$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$ and some parameter $\beta >0$.
- White noise convolved with a Gaussian kernel: the process $w_t=\int_{\mathbb R} \omega_s \Phi_{t-s} d s$

**Known so far:**

- Properties of $ w_t$: this is a mean-zero stationary Gaussian process with smooth sample paths and autocovariance given by

$$\kappa(h):=\mathbb E[w_t w_{t+h}] =e^{-\frac\beta 2h^2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2 \beta}}.$$

- For any $n \in\mathbb N$, the derivative process $w^{(n)}_t:=\frac{d^n}{dt^n}w_t$ is a mean zero stationary Gaussian process with autocovariance
  $\mathbb E[w^{(n)}_t w^{(n)}_{t+h}]= (-1)^n\kappa^{(2n)}(h)$. The latter comes from the **relation**:

\begin{equation}
\label{eq: autocov n m}
    \mathbb E[w^{(n)}_t w^{(m)}_{t+h}]= (-1)^n\kappa^{(n+m)}(h).
\end{equation}

To prove the relation we first **claim**:
$
    \mathbb E[w_t w^{(m)}_{t+h}]= \kappa^{(m)}(h).
$
We **prove the claim** by induction on $m$. The case $m=0$ is the definition. We show the statement for $m\geq 1$ assuming it holds for $m-1$:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[w_t w^{(m)}_{t+h}] &= \lim_{s \to 0}\frac 1 s\mathbb E[w_{t}(w^{(m-1)}_{t+h+s}-w^{(m-1)}_{t+h})]\\
&= \lim_{s \to 0}\frac 1 s \left( \kappa^{(m-1)}(h+s)-\kappa^{(m-1)}(h)\right) \\
&= \kappa^{(m)}(h).
\end{align*}

We now **prove the relation**.
Fix $m\geq 0$. We prove the relation by induction on $n$. The case $n=0$ is the claim. We show the statement for $n\geq 1$ assuming it holds for $n-1$:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[w^{(n)}_t w^{(m)}_{t+h}]&= \lim_{s \to 0}\frac 1 s\mathbb E[(w^{(n-1)}_{t+s}-w^{(n-1)}_t)w^{(m)}_{t+h}]\\
&= \lim_{s \to 0}\frac 1 s \left( \mathbb E[w^{(n-1)}_{t+s} w^{(m)}_{t+h}]- \mathbb E[w^{(n-1)}_{t} w^{(m)}_{t+h}]\right)\\ %intermediate step
&= (-1)^{n-1}\lim_{s \to 0}\frac 1 s \left( \kappa^{(n-1+m)}(h-s)-\kappa^{(n-1+m)}(h)\right) \\
&=(-1)^{n}\lim_{s \to 0}\frac 1 s \left( \kappa^{(n-1+m)}(h+s)-\kappa^{(n-1+m)}(h)\right) \\ %intermediate step
&=(-1)^{n}\kappa^{(n+m)}(h).
\end{align*}

Comment: Do you have a reference to your last display?

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't. The intermediate calculation is relatively long so I won't include it here unless it turns out to be particularly relevant.

Comment: Yes, I think this is relevant (and I actually doubt that it is true). Can you provide a link to the derivation of this equality?

Comment: Interesting! @IosifPinelis the derivation is much shorter than I remembered it so I've included it at the end of the post. Let me know if you find any mistakes. Note also that the permutation between derivatives and expectations is formal.

Comment: do you have a reference for the derivation of the autocovariance?

Comment: I think I figured it out: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4720470/445105 (the constant is slightly different)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $t \mapsto w_t$ extends to an entire function $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ with probability $1$.
Here is an explicit construction for $(w_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$.
Let $(X_n)_{n \ge 0}$ be independent real standard normal random variables, and let
$$w_t := (\frac{\pi}{2 \beta})^\frac{1}{4} e^{-\frac{\beta}{2} t^2} \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{X_n}{\sqrt{n!}} (\sqrt{\beta} t)^n$$
for $t \in \mathbb{R}$.
A basic fact about normal distributions:
If $d \ge 1$, $v_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$ for $n \ge 0$, and $\sum_n \|v_n\|^2 < \infty$, then $V = \sum_n X_n v_n$ is a real $d$-dimensional normal random vector, with $E[V] = 0$ and $E[V V^T] = (\sum_n (v_n)_p (v_n)_q)_{p,q \in \{1,\dotsc, d\}}$.
So $(w_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ is joint normal, $E(w_t) = 0$, and $E[w_t w_{t+h}] = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2 \beta}} e^{-\frac{\beta}{2} (t^2 + (t+h)^2)} \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{1}{n!} (\sqrt{\beta} t)^n (\sqrt{\beta} (t+h))^n = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2 \beta}} e^{-\frac{\beta}{2} h^2}$.
We can extend $w_t$ to $t \in \mathbb{C}$, then $E[\overline{w_t} w_{t+h}] = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2 \beta}} e^{-\frac{\beta}{2} (\overline{t}^2 + (t+h)^2) + \beta \overline{t} (t+h)} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2 \beta}} e^{-\frac{\beta}{2} (h + 2 \operatorname{Im}(t) i)^2}$.
Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{C^n}{\sqrt{n!}} = 0$ for every $C>0$, to show that $t \mapsto w_t$ is analytic with probability $1$, it is enough to show that if $q \in (0,1)$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} q^n X_n = 0$ with probability $1$ (this is easy to check).

One could even use this method to simulate $(w_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ or $(w_t)_{t \in \mathbb{C}}$ for not too big $t$'s, by choosing a big enough $N$ and using $w_t \approx (\frac{\pi}{2 \beta})^\frac{1}{4} e^{-\frac{\beta}{2} t^2} \sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} \frac{X_n}{\sqrt{n!}} (\sqrt{\beta} t)^n$ (for bigger $t$'s the convergence is slower, so one needs a bigger $N$).
I am sure there are faster algorithms, especially for big $t$'s, but at least this is pretty simple.

Comment: Thank you. If I understand correctly the first four lines following your display equation show that $w_t$, as defined in the display equation, coincides with $w_t$ as defined in the original post?

Comment: @Lance Both stochastic processes are smooth, Gaussian, and they have the same mean value $0$, and the same covariances, so they are essentially the same, they can be identified. If you want, you could also go in the opposite direction: start from your definition of $w_t$, and study the coefficients of the Taylor series of $e^{\frac{\beta}{2} t^2} w_t$ around $t = 0$. These are joint Gaussian, and one can show that they are independent (calculate the covariances), so multiplying by the appropriate constants to make the variance $1$, we get $X_n$.

Comment: By the way, another proof: you could get $w_t$ by smoothing white noise twice. After the first smoothing, we get continuous paths, which do not grow too fast (e.g., $e^{-C |t|} w_t \to 0$ as $|t| \to \infty$ with probability $1$ for $C > 0$), and the convolution of such a function with a Gaussian is always entire (analysis fact).

Comment: Upon a closer look, I am still confused at the proof: 1) I don't understand the justification for why $w_t$ is joint Gaussian. The basic fact about normal distributions you mentioned seems to only justify that $w_t$ is Gaussian for each $t$ instead.

Comment: 2) Also, showing that $w_t$ as defined in your post has the same statistics as the GP in the original post shows that they are modifications, ie same with probability 1. If one instead follows the approach in your comment to show that the former is the Taylor expansion at zero of the latter, then this would show that they are sample equivalent, correct? Your proof seems to then imply the stronger statement that your $w_t$ is sample analytic, which would then demonstrate that the original GP is also sample analytic.

Comment: 3) I cannot seem to see where you use the continuation onto C of the process. Is the sentence prior to your last paragraph meant to show that the series converges and thus defines a holomorphic function? But isn't the basic fact about normal distributions meant to show that this series converges already?

Comment: @Lance The basic fact is only used to show that $w_t$ are joint normal: if $t_1, \dotsc, t_d \in \mathbb{R}$, and $V = (w_{t_j})_{j=1}^d$, then $V = \sum_n X_n v_n$, where $v_n = ((\frac{\pi}{2\beta})^{\frac{1}{4}} e^{-\frac{\beta}{2} t_j^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}} (\sqrt{\beta} t_j)^n )_{1 \le j \le d}$, so $V$ is normal by the basic fact. The Taylor series around $0$ converges with probability $1$, so it extends to a holomorphic function. You have asked if the sample paths are analytic with probability 1. They are, and not just real analytic, they extend to an entire function on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now. One last thing: do you know of a reference for the basic fact on normal random variables?

Comment: I do not have a reference, but I have found these links: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674128/infinite-sum-of-normals, and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110461/infinite-sum-of-normal-r-v-is-still-a-normal-r-v-when-given-sum-limits-i-1